# mysql Workbench - Error Code: 1267 inside a function

Tags: mysql, collation

I have developed a function with an IF statement inside. The function works fine, until it gets inside the IF, where I get the error:

Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8_bin,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '<=' .

If I suppress the '<=', everything works fine.

I check the collation of the tables and database, it is utf8_bin, so many advices already read did not work.

Any ideas?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `mutare_interval`(v_id_inspectie INT(10), v_user varchar(100),new_start_time varchar(100), new_end_time varchar(100), new_date DATE) RETURNS varchar(100) 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

DECLARE v_mesaj VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE v_count VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE v_test VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE new_interval VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE old_start_time TIME;
DECLARE old_end_time TIME;
DECLARE old_date DATE;
DECLARE old_interval VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE old_user VARCHAR(100);

SET new_interval=concat ( left(new_start_time,5),'..',left(new_end_time,5),' ', new_date) COLLATE utf8_bin;

SELECT 
    start_time, end_time , start_date , CONCAT(LEFT(old_start_time, 5),
            '..',
            LEFT(old_end_time, 5),
            ' ',
            old_date) ,user INTO old_start_time, old_end_time, old_date, old_interval,old_user
FROM
    calendar
WHERE
    id_inspectie = v_id_inspectie;

SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
INTO v_count FROM
    calendar
WHERE
    user = v_user AND start_date = new_date
        AND (start_time<=new_end_time AND new_start_time<=end_time);

IF v_count=0 THEN 

-- facem update in Calendar pentru ca avem loc

UPDATE calendar SET start_time=new_start_time, end_time=new_end_time, start_date=new_date, end_date=new_date, user=v_user, 
start_date_time=CONCAT(new_date,' ',new_start_time), end_date_time=CONCAT(new_date,' ',new_end_time) WHERE id_inspectie=v_id_inspectie;

-- stergem intervalul vechi si cel nou in free time frames

DELETE FROM free_time_frames 
WHERE
    user_name = v_user
    AND LEFT(datestart , 10) = old_date
    AND (time_start<=old_end_time  AND old_start_time<=time_end);

DELETE FROM free_time_frames 
WHERE
    user_name = v_user
    AND LEFT(datestart , 10) = new_date
    AND (time_start <= new_end_time AND new_start_time <= time_end);

-- inserez intervale libere pe intervalul ramas liber (old)

INSERT INTO free_time_frames (interval_showv2,interval_show,id_activitate,durata_interval,time_start,time_end,datestart,
        dateend,dateendx,id,StartBreakLunch,EndBreakLunch,hh_name,wd,day_period,generation_time,user_name) 
        SELECT interval_showv2,interval_show,id_activitate,durata_interval,time_start,time_end,datestart,
        dateend,dateendx,id,StartBreakLunch,EndBreakLunch,hh_name,wd,day_period,generation_time,  old_user 
        FROM gth_ir.free_time_frames WHERE user_name='%ghost' AND LEFT(datestart,10)=old_date 
        AND (time_start <= old_end_time AND old_start_time <= time_end);


SET v_mesaj='Intervalul a fost modificat! ';

ELSE 

SET v_mesaj='Intervalul nu este eligibil! ';

END IF;
RETURN v_mesaj;
END
```

Comment: which line gives the error ?

Comment: AND (time_start<=old_end_time  AND old_start_time<=time_end); - after the first delete. Actually any line I will write containing  '<=' will give this error...

Comment: What charset and collation is the column?  What charset and collation do you establish when connecting to the database server?

Comment: I have default Charset utf8 and Collation utf8_bin. Same for the connection. The latin1_swedish appeared only when I added the "<=" symbol.

Comment: Which "default"?

Comment: The columns has the default Charset and Collation as initially set for this database: utf8 and utf8_bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had time values that were compared. As soon as I treated the time as seconds (`TIME_TO_SEC(time value)`), the error disappeared.

The correct code replaced all conditions where "<", ">", "=", "<=", "=>" operators where used in combination with time values with TIME_TO_SEC.

**Example:**

From:  `AND (start_time<=new_end_time AND new_start_time<=end_time);`

To:  `AND (TIME_TO_SEC(start_time)<=TIME_TO_SEC(new_end_time) AND TIME_TO_SEC(new_start_time)<=TIME_TO_SEC(end_time));`